# Urban Code deploy: How to use ${p:stepName/propName}?

Tags: properties, urbancode

I have a groovy script step in my process, this script sets a output property. I want to use this property value to set a property on a subsequent step.
Or
Simply use this property value in another groovy script step in my process.
The documentation says i need to use ${p:stepName/propName}. But how do I use it. can anyone give me an example. 
Assume that the process is the following
1) groovy step with name 'Run Groovy Step', this set the value of property 'CityName' to 'London'.
2) groovy step that wants to use the value of 'CityName'.
**How do i use ${p:stepName/propName}?** 
**is it ${p:Run Groovy Step/CityName}?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's basically it. You set the output property either with Groovy or in the post-processing script of a step. Then you access it with `${p:stepName/propName}` or with `properties.get(stepName/propName)`. Your code `${p:Run Groovy Step/CityName}` should work.

For an example: 
http://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.2/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/output_properties.html

Comment: Does this work even when step name has spaces? Can you give a simple groovy script that I can look at.

Comment: It should work even if the step name has spaces. I don't use Groovy so I don't have any examples for you. Maybe if you posted a snippet someone who uses Groovy can help you.